# Publish UIWebView texts on Facebook [iPhone SDK]

Tags: iphone, sdk

i have UIWebView and some text on there so i want publish my text messages to the facebook . how can publish my text on the facebook ? is there special API ? is tehre any Sample Code or tutorial? like this :

[alt text http://www.freezpic.com/pics/93f28f4f9103f0842c849d7daa644f81.jpg](http://www.freezpic.com/pics/93f28f4f9103f0842c849d7daa644f81.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook provides its Facebook Connect for iPhonw SDK. download and info [here](http://developers.facebook.com/connect.php?tab=iphone).
Also included a sample project.

Comment: How does it work ? it means the facbook connect publish UIWebview Texts ?

Comment: You can use Facebook Connect to publish your text to either your wall, updating your status or to the wall of your friends after getting the required permissions. The text provenance it's up to you: may be it comes from a textfield, a textview, from a file, from a database table etc.

Comment: thank you . another question i don't have any applications for Facebook . but here :
http://www.freezpic.com/pics/c652ce26ebd9fdef265fdf89a4c13b08.PNG
ask me MYAPIKEY and MYSECRET . but i don't have ! what can i do ?

Comment: register as a facebook developer and add your own application. You will be provided with the application api key and secret.

Comment: hi again . can check this question ? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180603/publish-uiwebview-via-facebook-connect

i've done everything but ...