# Publish UIWebview via Facebook connect

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, fbconnect

I am using `fbConnect` in my Cocoa Touch application. I have `UIWebview` on my view, and I want to publish the UIWebview's context (its only text) to FaceBook.

How should I change the `FBStream` to publish my UIWebview?

```
FBStreamDialog* dialog2 = [[[FBStreamDialog alloc] init] autorelease];
            dialog2.delegate = self;
            dialog2.userMessagePrompt = @"Share Ghazals on your wall";
            dialog2.attachment = @"{\"name\":\"Hafez Application for iPhone\","
            "\"href\":\"http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/divan-of-hafez/id340865571?mt=8?tab=iphone\","
            "\"media\":[{\"type\":\"image\","
            "\"src\":\"http://photos-h.ak.fbcdn.net/photos-ak-sf2p/v43/67/279420942343/app_5_279420942343_8373.gif\","
            "\"href\":\"http://developers.facebook.com/connect.php?tab=iphone/\"}],"
            "\"properties\":{\"another link\":{\"text\":\"Hafez App HomePage\",\"href\":\"http://www.momeks.com/hafez\"}}}";
            // replace this with a friend's UID
            // dialog.targetId = @"999999";
            [dialog2 show];
```

Here is my UIWebView Code:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"webViewContent" ofType:@"html"];
     NSFileHandle *readHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:path];

     NSString *htmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: 
                             [readHandle readDataToEndOfFile] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

     webView.opaque = NO;
     webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
     [self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
     [htmlString release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand what you mean by sharing UIWebview context.

If you want to publish text, then there are numerous examples for that on FBConnect.

You might want to try ShareKit, as it makes everything very easy....

If you could please re-explain the question, I could offer better help.

Godspeed,
Oded.